# Login regular expression

Tags: regex

Login - it is string of 1 - 10 symbols. Requirements:

```
the first symbol: 'letter';
middle symbols: 'letter' or 'digit' or '.' or '-';
the last symbol: 'letter' or 'digit';
```

I've tried the following Regular Expression, it works fine:

```
login = "Men-777.99";//true
regex = "^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.-]{0,8}[a-zA-Z0-9]$";
```

But I have a problem with login of length equals 1:

```
login = "M";//in that case my RegExp doesn't work
```

Comment: Can you clarify `problem with login with length of 1` requirement.

Comment: @anubhava User can enter the login of 1 symbol, but my RegExp doesn't allowed it.

Comment: In that case answer by @Braj should work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to to match single letter as well then make others **optional**.

Use `?` that represent 0 and 1 time, just enclose it inside the parenthesis `(...)?` and make it optional

```
^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9.-]{0,8}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

[Live DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hK2hJ4/2)

---

#### EDIT

To match exactly 1 and 10 digits you have to change it:

```
^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9.-]{8}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

because here `{0,8}` means 0 and 8 times where `{8}` means exactly 8 times.

Comment: thank you. Your decision with **parentheses** works. It saved me a day.